# Table cell align content right using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the table below, I have two rows. In the first row, second cell, I have two buttons. How can I get these buttons to be right aligned using **Twitter Bootstrap** The buttons should not stack on top of one another if I shrink the table. They should always be side by side.

```
[     ] [[button1] [button2]           ]
[     ] [                              ]
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/MycjXnp9wp. The buttons should be right aligned in the cell
A failed attempt: http://www.bootply.com/4hkmjHCCOq

This shows the output I am expecting. http://www.bootply.com/tYzdIu13M8 I would rather use the bootstrap way than the nested table technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the buttons right, bootstrap gives us the .pull-right classe :

```
    <td class="col">
      <div class="pull-right"><a href="test.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Go here</a></div>
      <div class="pull-right"><a href="test.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Go here</a></div>
    </td>
```

And we should use `display:inline-flex;` on the .col class to make the two buttons aligned always even after shrinking the table.

```
.col{
    display:inline-flex;
    float:right;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/dq7zjsLm/4/)

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear. The goal is to right align the buttons within the cell.

Comment: pull-right - exactly what I was looking for! Can you move this to the main answer so that I can mark this as answered? Thanks for your help! Btw, are the additional css classes required? They seem to work without it: http://jsfiddle.net/dq7zjsLm/3/

Comment: the .col class is required so the buttons will stay inline, i'll edit the main answer now